# Two different table with 2 different AJAX JSON response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I'm new to `javascript`.

I need to fetch `JSON` response from 2 different `AJAX` request and create a 2 different table.

I have achieved it for 1 JSON response and 1 Table.

HTML :

```
<div style="width:700px;padding:20px;S">
                    <table id="host_table" class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Server Name</th>
                            <th>Availability %</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
$(function() {

    // kick off with fetchdata
     fetchData();
//   fetchServiceData();
});
function make_base_auth(user, password) {
            var tok = user + ':' + password;
            var hash = btoa(tok);
            return 'Basic ' + hash;
}

function fetchData() {
  var time = new Date();
  var end =  Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000);
  //var end = ~~(Date.now() /1000) ;
  var start = Math.floor(time.setDate(time.getDate() - 1)/1000);
  Availreport = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/nagios/cgi-bin/archivejson.cgi?query=availability&availabilityobjecttype=hostgroups&hostgroup=ALM&assumedinitialhoststate=up&assumedinitialservicestate=ok&starttime=" + start + "&endtime=" + end;

 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: Availreport,
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',
                        make_base_auth("nagiosadmin", "nagiosadmin"));
                },

 dataType: 'json',     //data format
 //async: false,
 //success: onOutboundReceived      //on receive of reply
 timeout: 0,
 success: availshow 

 });

  function availshow(series) {

  // 1. remove all existing rows
    $("tr:has(td)").remove();

    $.each(series.data.hostgroup.hosts, function (index, test) {  
  $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(test.name),
            $('<td>').text(parseInt(((test.time_up - test.time_down)/test.time_up)*100)),
        ).appendTo('#host_table');          
    });

    $('#host_table tr').each(function() {
  var $td = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');
  var value = $td.text();
  if (parseInt(value) < 100) {
    $td.css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });

}
```

This works perfect for 1 table creation.

But I'm unable to proceed for 2 table creation for 2 `JSON` response.

I can able to create 2 tables in `HTML`.

But unable to feed the JSON response to specific table.

HTML for 2 table Creation :

```
            <table id="host_table" class="inlinetable" style="display: inline-block;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Server Name</th>
                    <th>Availability %</th>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table id="service_table" class="inlinetable" style="display: inline-block;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Service Name</th>
                    <th>Availability %</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

How to achieve my task?

Comment: could you please share the sample table with sample data

Comment: are you getting data for both table from same ajax

Comment: First put debug at this line `$("tr:has(td)").remove();`
then check what response is coming from first call and why its not working.
In case its giving error then please mention the error messages and the response for both the calls in the question.

Comment: @AhmedSunny  i need to use 2 ajax for 2 tables

Comment: i dont know whats confusing you, just create two ajax, and create two tables and ad tbody and thead, and update each table from its specific ajax, you have differnet table id, so use table id tbody to append or html

Comment: create another function  fetchData2(); and you can update table in success function, or you want dynamic function ? if yes, then pass series and table id to  function availshow(table_id,series)  and use this id

Comment: @AhmedSunny It works :). One small query, the table display one below the other. I want it to be displayed side by side

Comment: i added it in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make tables side by side like this
its another question but
use  for first table

> style="display: inline-block;"

and for second table

> style="float: left;">

```
   <table id="host_table" class="inlinetable" style="display: inline-block;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Server Name</th>
            <th>Availability %</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

    <table id="service_table" class="inlinetable" style="float: left;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Service Name</th>
            <th>Availability %</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

JS

```
$(function() {

// kick off with fetchdata
//   service_table();
service_table();
//   host table();
fetchData2();

});


function service_table() {

 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: Availreport,
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',
          make_base_auth("nagiosadmin", "nagiosadmin"));
     },
 dataType: 'json',
 timeout: 0,
 success:function(series) {

   $('#service_table tbody').empty();
     // your row loop code
  }

 });
function service_table() {

 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: Availreport,
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',
          make_base_auth("nagiosadmin", "nagiosadmin"));
     },
 dataType: 'json',
 timeout: 0,
 success:function(series) {

   $('#host_table tbody').empty();
       // your row loop code
  }

 });


}
```

its just how it can work for your understanding, more dynamic solution can be made

Comment: Still my table list one below the another only

Comment: remove class inlinetable from both, i think its your custom class that could be problem

Comment: great  you found it

Comment: Thanks for the timely support